# reuse controllers, views and services in angular app

Tags: angularjs

I want my app to fetch data from a server API, lets say I have the following API `/orders` , `/users`. Basically I just want to display the json I get from the server in a table. I am using ng-table directive for that purpose. So, in terms of components I have :

1. Services - both services do the same thing - go to an API and fetch JSON
2. Views - same view for both of the APIs, just display different data
3. Controllers - both fetch data from the service and display it in the table view.

So the way I see it, they all do the same thing with very minor adjustments. What I would like to do is

```
angular.module('admin').config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  // same template and controller for both
  $routeProvider.
    when('/users', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/table.html',
      controllers: '/js/controllers/table.js
    }).
    when('/orders', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/table.html',
      controllers: '/js/controllers/table.js'
    });
});
```

And in my service

```
factory('AdminService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  // somehow I want to inject the right endpoint, depending on the route
  return $resource( '/:endpoint',
    { }, {} );
}]);
```

And in my table controller as well, I want to be able to know what to pass to the service

I could of course use separate controllers and services for each API endpoint it just seems like a wasteful duplication of code that does 99% the same thing

Is this possible ?

How do I wire everything together ?

Comment: Is it a problem to write two method in one service for accessing your APIs?

Comment: @Alborz not a problem, just trying to figure out the best way to minimise code duplication, also how to wire everything together to use one controller, view and service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want separate routes, but the same controller, but with some options, you can use the `resolve` option in the route definition to pass some options:

```
$routeProvider.
when('/users', {
  templateUrl: '/partials/table.html',
  controller: 'TableController',
  resolve: {
     'option1': function() {
        return 'val1'
     },
     'option2': function() {
        return 'val2'
     }
  }
}).
when('/orders', {
  templateUrl: '/partials/table.html',
  controller: 'TableController',
  resolve: {
     'option1': function() {
        return 'val3'
     },
     'option2': function() {
        return 'val4'
     }
  }
});
```

Then the controller in both cases will be injected with "option1" and "option2", which can be used to customise its behaviour:

```
app.controller('TableController', function($scope, option1, option2) {
  // Do something with option1 or option1
});
```

From the `resolve` object functions, you could return a `$resource` object, or even return a promise that will be resolved with some data before the route is displayed. You can see the [docs for `$routeProvider`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) for details.

Edit: For the resource, you could write a configurable factory like:

```
app.factory('MyResource', function($resource) {
  return function(endpoint) {
    return $resource('/' + endpoint);
  }
});
```

And then use it in the controller:

```
app.controller('TableController', function($scope, MyResource, endpoint) {
  var currentResource = MyResource(endpoint);
  currentResource.query(); // Whatever you want to do with the $resource;
}
```

assuming that "endpoint" was was one of the options added in the `resolve`, so something like

```
when('/orders', {
  templateUrl: '/partials/table.html',
  controller: 'TableController',
  resolve: {
     'endpoint': function() {
        return '/orders'
     }
```

Comment: I was just reading about `resolve`, you're right sounds like exactly what I need. The only missing piece I have is the service, how would you suggest implementing the service so that I could inject the endpoint to it as well ?

Comment: @Michael I have added how you could do that, passing endpoint into a configurable factory.

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks for the great answer